# modal opens just fine on codepen, but not on shopify

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, shopify

I spent time coding a nice size chart for my Shopify store and got everything where I want it on [codepen](https://codepen.io/jstormthakid/pen/RwgwxXp), but when I dropped all the code into [Shopify](https://kingofthepin.com/collections/t-shirts/products/eyes-of-black-lady-black-s-s-t-shirt), it doesn't open, I'm sure it's a javascript issue but I wouldn't even know where to start to look.

any help/guidance would be appreciated on this.

thank you.

---

////// html //////

```
<div class="product-info__size-chart-line">
  <div class="product-info__size-chart" data-size-chart-handle="size-guide"><button id="myBtn" type="button" class="product-info__size-chart-link">Size Chart</button>
   </div>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>

    <div id="kotp-size-chart">

    <h2>Men's T-Shirt <br> Size Chart</h2>

      <table class="table kotp-size-chart-table">
        <thead class="">
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Size</th>
            <th colspan="2">Width</th>
            <th colspan="2">Length</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="incm-header">in</td>
            <td class="incm-header">cm</td>
            <td class="incm-header">in</td>
            <td class="incm-header">cm</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sizes-header">S</td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>71</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sizes-header">m</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>74</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sizes-header">l</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>76</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sizes-header">xl</td>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>31</td>
            <td>79</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sizes-header">2x</td>
            <td>26</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>81</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sizes-header">3x</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>71</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>84</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sizes-header">4x</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>76</td>
            <td>34</td>
            <td>86</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sizes-header">5x</td>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>81</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>89</td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
    
  </div>

</div>
```

////// js //////

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your script tag and it doesn't add the script to the website.
You need to check the tag and use the liquid tag `script_tag`.
Read more about [script_tag](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters/html-filters#script_tag)

```
{{ 'size-chart-modal.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: ok so I just updated that (thank you for pointing that out) and it is now connected to my site but it still does nothing when clicked. any other ideas?

Comment: I think you need to add the script into the footer of the page into the body tag just before `</body>` closing, I think the code runs firstly and HTML is appended after it so that's why it is not working.

Comment: Bro! That worked!  Thank you for your help! Now to fix these little css issues.  Thanks again my friend!

Comment: glad to know this solution works for you